# Sharepoint survey - Start immediately the Survey in modal popup

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog, survey

I have a problem: I would like to start immediately a survey create in sharepoint 2010, in the normal popup window, immediately at the moment when the overview page is loaded, wihout the need to click "Respond to this survey".

I.e.: clicking on site quick toolbar and start immediately with the modal popup form.

Please, do you have any suggestion for this task?

Thanks!

R.